# strip() method does not work on str class

Tags: python, string, python-3.7

First, I have `bytes` class object "myst". I then convert it to a `str` class using `str()`, and remove the whitespace using the `strip()` method. The problem is that the whitespace "\r\n" is not removed.

```
>>> myteststring=b'asdf\r\n'
>>> str(myteststring)
"b'asdf\\r\\n'"
>>> str(myteststring).strip()
"b'asdf\\r\\n'"
```

But, using the `strip()` method on a `byte` class works properly.

```
>>> byteclass=b'asdf\r\n'
>>> byteclass.strip()
b'asdf'
```

What's wrong here?

---

I think when I use `str()`, the resulting string includes double back slash `\\`. This is may be root of my problem.

```
>>> myteststring
b'asdf\r\n'
>>> str(myteststring)
"b'asdf\\r\\n'"   # << this is problem ??
```

Comment: i don't know why image doesn't uploaded. so i add my code and execution result as text.

Comment: I reversed my downvote on the basis of you you converting the images to text. You shouldn't have been posting images of code in the first place. This is not.. great... but it's much better, thanks.

Comment: `strip()` removes characters only from edges of the string. When converting bytes to string, you add quotes on the edges of the string, so nothing is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passed a `bytes` object without an `encoding` argument, the `str` function would simply call the `repr` function to return the string representation of the given `bytes` object, which is why `str(myteststring)` returns `"b'asdf\\r\\n'"`, with `\r\n` escaped with additional backslashes.

You can properly convert a `bytes` object to a string by passing to the `str` function an `encoding` argument instead:

```
>>> myteststring=b'asdf\r\n'
>>> str(myteststring, encoding='utf-8')
'asdf\r\n'
>>> str(myteststring, encoding='utf-8').strip()
'asdf'
```